# Creating an ascending sorting function

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort an array of 10000 random integers and plot it into a graph. Technically, the code does sort in ascending order however somewhere during the sorting process it resets a bunch of the values to be the same. Where it looks like a step function where it should just be a continuous line.

```
 A;  
 for j = 1 : Nx-1    
     minvalue = A(j) ; 
     pointerminvalue = j ;
    for i = j : Nx        
        if (A(i) < minvalue )         
            minvalue = A(i)  ;         
            pointerminvalue = i ;     
        end
    end
    maxvalue = A(j) ;     
    A(j) = A(pointerminvalue) ;    
    A(pointerminvalue) = minvalue ;  
    % dont put the end here 
    A ;  
 end
```

Any know where I am possibly making the mistake?

Comment: Any specific reason not to use `sort`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
maxvalue = A(j) ;     
A(j) = A(pointerminvalue) ;    
A(pointerminvalue) = minvalue ;
```

You are using two different variable names, change it to

```
H = A(j) ;     
A(j) = A(pointerminvalue) ;    
A(pointerminvalue) = H ;
```